# Underlying stream returned zero bytes

Tags: java, io, inputstream, filestream

I'm currently writing my own Brainfuck interpreter in Java and because I want it to be able to read code from files I wrote a `BFInputStream` that filters unnecessary symbols out. It looks like this:

```
import java.io.FilterInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BFInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    public BFInputStream(InputStream in) {
        super(in);
    }
    public int read() throws IOException {
        while(true) {
            int i = super.read();
            // keep LF for line number checking.
            if(i == -1 || i == 10 ||( i >= 43 && i <= 46) || i == 60 || i == 62 || i == 91 || i == 93)
                return i;
        }
    }
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if(off < 0 || len < 0 || len > b.length - off) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            int j = read();
            if(j < 1) return i;
            b[off+i] = (byte)j;
        }
        return len;
    }
}
```

My Interpreter uses `LineNumberReader`<-`InputStreamReader`<-`BFInputStream`<-`FileInputStream` to read the file. But everytime it reaches the end of the file it throws:

> java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes
>
> ```
>   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:268)
>   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
>   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
>   at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
>   at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
>   at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:157)
>   at java.io.LineNumberReader.read(LineNumberReader.java:108)
>   at Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:101)
>   at Interpreter.main(Interpreter.java:180)
> ```

Interpreter.java:101 contains a call to `BFInputStream.read()`.

I'm not sure if I understand the exception correctly. I think the stream returned no bytes at all (because of a timeout). I guess if there was a huge chunk of non-BF characters then that could be possible but at the end of the file? `FileInputStream` and therefore `FilterInputStream` and `BFInputStream` should return -1.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (j < 1)` should be `if (j < 0)`, because EOF is indicated by `-1`. Also, your method never returns -1 at EOF.

The correct implementation would look like this:

```
public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    if(off < 0 || len <= 0 || len > b.length - off) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();         
    int i = 0;
    while (i < len) {
        int j = read();
        if (j < 0) break; // Stop reading at EOF
        b[off + i] = (byte) j;
        i++;
    }
    if (i == 0) return -1; // If we get EOF with no data, return it to the caller
    else return i;
}
```

Comment: Exept that you forgot casting `j` to byte it works perfectly, thank you. I simply forgot to add the check for -1. But I have no idea how the 1 instead of a 0 got there.

Comment: @IchBinKeinBaum: Your code produces 0 if you get EOF at the first iteration.

Comment: Yes I noticed. What I meant was I have no idea why I wrote `if(j < 1)` instead of `if(j < 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Well did same kinda thing before but using File, FileReader/Writer and BufferReader/Writer.
I am giving you the snippet of code i use as guidelines.. try it

For Reading from a file

```
File f = new File("my.txt");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(fr);

String s = null;

while ((br=readLine())!=null) {

// Do whatever u want to do with the content of the file.

}

br.close();
```

For Writing to a file:

```
Boolean isDone = true;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
File f = new File("my.txt");
FileWriter fr = new FileWriter(f);
BufferedWriter br  = new BufferedWriter(fr);

while (b) {

   if (!b) {

 br.write(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());

 }


}
```